# how to split string and take only the first string (a number) in python?

Tags: python, pandas, split

I have this column in my dataframe, and I want to split the number and the string, and take only the number which is 1, 2, 3, and 4.

```
type
2 type (a, b)
4 type (a, b, c, d)
3 type (a, b, c)
1 CYCLE (a)
```

what I expect:

```
type
2
4
3
1
```

how should I write my script in order to split the number and get the expected column?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `str.extract` with the regex pattern `^\d+`:

```py
df["num"] = df["type"].str.extract(r'^(\d+)')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `split()` if all of your number in 'type' column is in the format `number type....`:

```
df['type']=df['type'].str.split(' ',1).str[0]
```